# How to load <script> inside AngularJS Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add google preview wizard api (https://developers.google.com/books/docs/preview-wizard) script inside my angularJS application.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> GBS_insertEmbeddedViewer('ISBN:0738531367',600,500);</script>
```

1. When I try to do this directly (or inside a div tag) inside a controller, it over writes the whole web page and just displays the preview button.
2. Same is the scenario with I try to load this piece of script with directives. (AEC)
3. Could not use ng-templates as keeping a script anything inside ng-template didn't make sense.
4. Closest I ever got to the problem is when I try to load this piece of script in the main index.html page. It gets loaded, but I'm not able to pass a variable ISBN in to the script (even keeping the isbn attached to scope ).
5. Data binding with the controller is not happening when ever the variable is inside the script tag

Please suggest a way out of this.

Comment: You have tried with iframe, I made an application with Angularjs and Google Maps, only when maps were inserted in an iframe worked well

Comment: Can you provide some code from what you've tried

Comment: Show the code for option 4 that you have tried.

Comment: @rkmax Thank you. I tried like this. <iframe src="http://books.google.com/books/previewlib.js">  <script type="text/javascript"> GBS_insertEmbeddedViewer('{{isbn}}',600,500);</script>
</iframe>. But I'm not able to bind the variables with the controller .Any help on this ?

Comment: @Asik Please refer to the code above in the comments. Similar to the above but inside a ng-controller. Data binding is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

angular has directives you can build one like this

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('embedViewer', ['$compile',function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: '<div></div',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                isbn: '=embedViewer'
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
                var rawTmpl = '<iframe src="books.google.com/books/previewlib.js">; <script type="text/javascript"> GBS_insertEmbeddedViewer("{{isbn}}",600,500);</script> </iframe>';
                scope.$watch('isbn', function(val) {
                    if (val) {
                        var template = $compile(rawTmpl)(scope);
                        el.html(template);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }]);
```

and you can use in any template like

```
<div embed-viewer="book.isbn"></div>
<!-- OR -->
<div data-embed-viewer="book.isbn"></div>
<!-- OR -->
<embed-viewer="book.isbn"></embed-viewer>
```

this code isnt tested

Comment: Thanks for your reply rkmax. I tried using your idea.But unfortunately google preview needs to execute the script, not just show a source website in an iframe. (in short there is no src param for iframe). Apart from this, did you come across a scenario where you have to load/embed a script inside your angular application ? That would be of some help